# PHP mail() send error but not report error

Tags: php

i'm running CentOS 64bit, install php 5.3.3 and i have php code like this

```
<?php
session_start(); 
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("max_execution_time", 1800);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Saigon');

mail("myemail@gmail.com","x","y","From: steve@a.com\n");
?>
```

Email not sent but also not reporting any error, i will edit in php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING
display_errors = On
```

Still no have error reporting...

Please help.

Comment: have your default smtp is set. ask from your server administrator

Comment: @SKRocks im are admin of this server.

Comment: Server administrator? from which you take hosting.

Comment: Do you have a SMTP server set up? Please tell me you're not running this on localhost.

Comment: @SKRocks I buy VPS with root access and i will install everything A-Z.

Comment: @ljacqu i will setup SMTP in php.ini with port 25, i buy two server, server A and B, server A i buy on digitalocean and this code work fine but server B i buy on diffrent company and don't working when send mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `Spf` protection. Try the below code and it'll work

```
<?php
session_start(); 
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("max_execution_time", 1800);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Saigon');

mail("myemail@gmail.com","x","y","From: steve@air.com\n");
?>
```

I replaced `apple.com` with `air.com` You can't use some domains like

1. `support@facebook.com`
2. `support@google.com` etc.

in php `mail()` as They are protected by  `Sender Policy Framework (SPF)` but if you want **you can use this and it'll work for any domain**:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("max_execution_time", 1800);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Saigon');

mail("myemail@gmail.com","x","y","From: steve@ apple.com\n");
?>
```

@
Note the space between `@`and `apple.com` but by using this method you can't send mail to `Yahoo` users. The best option is to buy a SMTP server to send mail peacefully!

Read more here: https://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny/spf

Comment: @AsheshKumar Please do not bug people to accept/vote for your posts.